# Testing GAC Style Plugin Architecture?

Tags: c#, plugins

**Background**

I have a deployed system that consists of:

- A few dozen "core" DLLs
- Hundreds of "plugins" that make use of the "core" DLLs

The core (and each plugin) are independently deployable, but the plugins can only execute correctly if they're deployed alongside the correct version of the core.

**The Problem**

What if the core gets modified in a way that breaks a plugin? The actual APIs/interfaces might remain the same, but a logic change within one of those methods could (in theory) cause negative downstream impacts. How can we prevent those?

This architecture is old and "GAC style" and isn't really what I'd suggest today. But it's what I have. I've started moving the "core" DLLs into individual nuget packages to try and move the system to a "bring your own" model. In the interim time, I am trying to figure out how to execute existing (~5000) integration tests on the core+plugins, but I'm having a hard time coming with a good way to achieve this

**What I have Tried**

You can't just compile the tests in the plugin's solution because the plugins won't necessarily be compiled against the latest core DLL set, they'll be at whatever version they consumed when they were last modified. Similarly, you can't try and attach the `*.csproj` files for those plugins to the core's solution because the plugin's xunit test project will be executing against the (outdated) nuget packages for that plugin.

The best I could come up with was:

- Publish each plugin with its test DLLs
- When building the core, consume all the plugins + test DLLs
- This will be the "latest" core, so will mimic what will happen if the core updates

I don't like this solution. It's awfully kludgy. Will it work? Yes, at least well enough to tell you that plugin X was broken and needs attention. Do I like it? Nope.

Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: Your question will likely close.  Stackoverflow doesn't do well on _opinion_ questions like _Does anyone have a better idea?_  I have no idea what you mean by GAC-style; the GAC is a pretty complicated structure, allowing it to hold, for example, multiple versions of strongly named assemblies.  Your question doesn't include enough information for anyone to meaningfully comment.  When I've done plug-in architectures, everything was defined in terms of interfaces, pretty much using COM-style interface versioning rules (i.e., you can't modify the contract at all).